# Adding a row to mySQL using a session and a form with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, pdo

I am trying to add a new row to a table in my database, there is only two columns in the table and i am using a form to get one of the fields. here is the form i am using

```
<form action="add_list.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="listname">
<input type="submit" value="Add List">
</form>
```

and here is add_list.php

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$username = "mydb";
$password = "mydb"; 
$member = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$listname = $_POST["listname"];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:;dbname=mydb', $username, $password);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO lists VALUES (:member_id, :listname)');
    $sth->execute(array(':member_id' => $member, ':listname' => $listname));

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();}
?>
```

I am currently getting an error on line five

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/danu2_cj3/public_html/add_list.php on line 5
```

how to I identify the session variable?

Here is the part of the login code i have set the session in

```
if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: lists.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login-failed.php");
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: use session_start(); before using $_SESSION.

Comment: i have tried that but it just give me a blank page and does not add it to the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages in the form of:

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION ...
```

are often caused by the lack of a `session_start` call at the beginning of the script (before the headers are sent and before any attempt to access a `$_SESSION` key is done).

---

> I have tried that but it just give me a blank page and does not add it to the table.

Well, that means that you have at least solved the above problem. For the blank page you should search for [white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death), which is well documented here as one of the most common problems in the PHP environment.